# How to get all types in the references that implement IMyInterface

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a project contains many references.
I need to find all the types that implement IMyInterface interface.

I tried `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())` but it didn't returned all the types in the references.

How do I do that?

Comment: PS. could it be you are loading a plugin DLL? It just might be loaded in a separate AppDomain :)

Comment: @sehe: How do I look on other AppDomain? What is actually the AppDomain??

Comment: That's evading the question. Are you loading a plugin DLL? Also, read [How to: Load Assemblies into an Application Domain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25y1ya39.aspx) and [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx) for starting points. Good luck

Comment: Can you give us some context, please. It's not clear to me where you want to put this code. Is it a VS add-in that has to inspect the references of the current project? Is it something which you use to inspect the references of a dll? Or is it something you want to use to inspect the references of the same project where you are writing this code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess the problem might be that some of your referenced assemblies are not currently loaded. You can get all referenced assemblies with [GetReferencedAssemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getreferencedassemblies.aspx) - but this will only yield the names.

If you want you can go on and load the assemblies with [Assembly.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4cw969y.aspx) and inspect them further.

So a possible snippet should be

```
    var types =
        System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
            .GetReferencedAssemblies()
            .SelectMany(name => Assembly.Load(name).GetTypes())
            .Union(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes()));
```

to search for the types implementing your interface:

```
    var withInterfaces =
        types.Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i == typeof(IDisposable)));
```

If this does not the trick I'm lost as well...

Comment: Can I know using AssemblyName if the assembly implements IMyInterface?

Comment: Assemblies don't implement interfaces; classes do.

Comment: Beware: this will spit out a lot of types - in my simple test application it's 8384 types!

Comment: I thought you know - you can use the types to check if they implement some interfaces

Comment: you can use GetInterface (might be quicker) but I think this one is more readable

Comment: have you checked my proposal? I'm really interested in the outcome but it's getting late and I'm getting tired ;)

Comment: @CKoenig: I checked it. This code: Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies().SelectMany(name => Assembly.Load(name).GetTypes()).Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i == typeof(IMyInterface))); returns me all the time only the IMyInterface class and not the types implement it. I am really don't know what is the problem.

Comment: strange - if I run this code with IDisposable I get a lot of types implementing it (over 700 of the 8384 types I find) - got it - you should combine this with your initial idea - seems like the Referenced Assemblies don't contain the current ones?

Comment: Even if I do: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(x=>x.GetReferencedAssemblies()).SelectMany(name => Assembly.Load(name).GetTypes()).Where(x => type.IsAssignableFrom(x)); I don't get the desire types. I must do something wrong, probably something silly but I don't know what..

Comment: @Naor: well, all the time you don't show it, we can't look at it to find the problem. Perhaps you could try with IDisposable as well, just to check whether the basics work...?

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

// try this for fun:
using IMyInterface=System.Collections.IEnumerable;

namespace TestThat
{
    class MainClass
    {

        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            var x = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
                .Where(t => typeof(IMyInterface).IsAssignableFrom(t))
                .Where(t => !(t.IsAbstract || t.IsInterface))
                .Except(new [] { typeof(IMyInterface) });

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", x.Select(y=>y.Name).ToArray()));

        }
    }
}
```

If looking for derived classes and want to 'skip' the base class:

```
            .Except(new [] { typeof(MyBaseClass) });
```

There is your interface detection. I'll have a look why you are not getting all types in references. I'd have expected your code to do that, Brb.

Comment: This returns only assemblies from the current domain.

Comment: Edit: I have just checked, this returns all classes from all referenced assemblies just fine for me.

Comment: I've put a reduced demo (only listing 100 random matches) online here: https://ideone.com/WUipr

Comment: Does Test1 and Test2 sit in the same assembly? I see that you put it in the same cs file.

Comment: Have you read he REST of the source? Note that currently `IMyInterface` is an alias for.... `System.Object` :) -- I actually put up a full working example online. See [link](https://ideone.com/WUipr). (_All you mention is that I also have tested with local interface and types. Note: I tested it_ )

Comment: IMyInterface sits in other assembly but Test1 and Test2 are in your current application assembly.

Comment: No. Removing apparently confusing code. Please read carefully. **[Have you checked the online demonstration (at all)](http://ideone.com/WUipr)**? I'm guessing you are just not used to seeing `using XXXX=System.Object;` in your code. I think it would be nice to ask what is going on, rather than to assume I'm the one who doesn't understand

Comment: Yes, I saw several times your demonstration but your code don't work for me.

Comment: @Naor: sorry about that. It must be something else you're doing, like my suggestion about AppDomains, or the way you check for a matching type. I'm afraid you'll have to provide more relevant details (like, erm, code?) to get more answers.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do this at runtime?

If you just need to know this information generally, and it doesn't have to be at runtime, you can just load up the solution in Visual Studio, then right click on the on the name of the interface in the interface IName { line, and then choose "Find all references" - this should show you all references to the interface in your code.

If it's something you really need at runtime, then see the above answer.